# any url scheme for default download manager in android

Tags: android, url-scheme

i need URL scheme for default android download manager. like whats app url scheme ( whatsapp://send?text=  ) as like line ( line://msg/text/ ). i need android default download manager's URL scheme to allow users download my design from my app . for ex:  `'downloadmanager://fileurl?file=http://domain.com/photo1.jpg'`  . please help me . i hope you understand my question

Comment: <a href="intent:// download manager   is this help me .. please provide full code how this will help me if this <a href="intent://andcode/http://example.com/photo1.jpg   something like this ???

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to send Intents to download manager.
Use this:

```
DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) _context.getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
        Request request = new Request(
                Uri.parse("http://www.example.com/path/image.jpg"));
        dm.enqueue(request);
```

Answer (score 0):

> i need URL scheme for default android download manager

There is no scheme specific to the Downloads app.

Comment: thanks ..but i just want to download images .. so i think maybe url scheme help me in this ..